# Python regular expressions in Alpine Linux

Tags: python, regex, docker, alpine-linux

I have something like this in my code:

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'^[\^ěščřžýáíéóúůďťňĎŇŤŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉÚŮA-Za-z0-9*+.,()<>=\/ -{}]*$')
match = pattern.match("áážžššěě")
if match:
    print "good"
else:
    print "not good"
```

When I run this on Ubuntu, it works as expected and prints "good". But when using Docker with Alpine Linux to run this, the script prints "not good". Why is this?

Comment: Ubuntu has many built-in languages pre-installed but that might not be the case of containerized image forked system.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, is that something I can fix or should I just use some other base image?

Comment: I would say you should try decoding it and then see if it works.

Comment: Why are you using bytestrings with non-ASCII characters?